# Using named pipes interface inside existing service class in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, service, interface, named-pipes

My project contains a service and a client app.
I want to use WCF (named pipes) to exchange data between them.

I 've added:

```
namespace MyService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPipeComm
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string PipeCommProc(string value);
    }

    //----------

    public class PipeComm : IPipeComm
    {
        public string PipeCommProc(string value)
        {
            return ("blah");
        }
    }

    //----------

    public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        ServiceHost PipeHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PipeComm), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") });
        ...
```

It works OK. 
But the problem is that inside PipeCommProc i want to use all data and methods of my service.
But since PipeComm is a different class i don't have access to them.
Is there a way to reconstruct this code in order to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ServiceHost can also take a real object instead of a type to construct every time. If you want to access your service class, the easiest way might be to have your service class implement the service interface and use the existing instance as a WCF service instance as well:

```
namespace MyService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPipeComm
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string PipeCommProc(string value);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]     
    public partial class MyService : ServiceBase, IPipeComm
    {
        public string PipeCommProc(string value)
        {
            return ("blah");
        }

        private readonly ServiceHost PipeHost;

        public MyService()
        {
            PipeHost = new ServiceHost(this, new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Is it possible to establish a full duplex async communication between service and process using two named pipes as above? One hosted by service and one by process? Can a process host a named pipe if it has no admin rights?

Comment: @monica It should be possible, I have not done it myself though.